# Best practice for coding Age Verification pop-up?

Tags: seo

SEO-wise, what is the best practice for coding Age Verification pop-up? As far as I understood:

1. It needs to be on the same page, not redirect.
2. It needs to be a Javascript overlay/pop-up.

Are there any other requirements? I don't completely understand how e.g/ Google Crawler processes that kind of pop-up? How do you guarantee it will click on "I'm 21 year old" and then process the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

Age-Gate is the "go-to" Wordpress plugin for this - so I guess, if in doubt, look at what it does (or if you use Wordpress, just use that)

If the popup uses Javascript (which I believe AgeGate does),  I expect Google will just not run the Javascript and will work fine anyway.

The requirements may be a little country specific - but at least where I am, its all the joke of "click here and I trust you are not lying to me".

Answer (score 0):

I would focus my attention in 2 things:

1. UX - A11Y best practices so anyone that comes into the site understand the purpose and how to deal with the modal window.
2. Dynamically load what needs to be loaded once the user do the confirmation. For instance, like Facebook or Twitter loads content on the scroll event.

Once the user take action into the modal window options, redirect the user to the door, if it's under 21. And do a full load of the content in case they decided to stay. Here I would say as well, to store somewhere that consent to avoid asking every load page time to the user the same question.